# filter array data in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.currentEvent = Object { item_id: "10535", name: "johnny", user_type: "1",category_id: "5"}, Object { item_id: "10534", name: "smith", user_type: "1",category_id: "6"}, Object { item_id: "10536", name: "Greg", user_type: "1",category_id: "7"};


$scope.users = Object { item_id: "11355", name: "mathew", user_type: "1",category_id: "7"}, Object { item_id: "10336", name: "Greg", user_type: "2",category_id: "7"}, Object { item_id: "10545", name: "powell", user_type: "1",category_id: "7"}, Object { item_id: "10456", name: "micheal", user_type: "3",category_id: "7"};
```

Need to filter base on user_type

```
Expected result = $scope.validUser = Object { item_id: "11355", name: "mathew", user_type: "1",category_id: "7"},  Object { item_id: "10545", name: "powell", user_type: "1",category_id: "7"};
```

My work
I used the below code doesn't work for me

```
$scope.validUser = $scope.validUser.filter(function($scope.currentEvent){
    return $scope.validUser.user_type === $scope.currentEvent.user_type;
});
```

Please guide: How can we fix it out?

Also explain the way we can get the result - how to filter data in angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.validUser = $scope.users.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.user_type === $scope.currentEvent.user_type;
});
```

- Filter on the `users` array not `validUser`.
- The filter argument is the object for the current iteration, so don't use `$scope` there.

Answer (score 0):

You had wrong code in `.filter` function, correct it to below. Specifically you should be looping over `$scope.users` object to filter out matched `user_type` property.

```
$scope.validUser = $scope.users.filter(function(item){ //<- don't use `$scope` here
    return $scope.validUser.user_type === item.user_type;
});
```

Using angular `$filter` API

```
$scope.validUser = $filter('filter')( $scope.users, {
   user_type: $scope.currentEvent.user_type 
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can create filter like below**

```
.filter('nbSearchFilter', function() {
    return function(input, nb) {
        var out = [];
        if (nb) {
            angular.forEach(input, function(natureofbusiness) {
                if (natureofbusiness.nb_title.toLowerCase().indexOf(nb.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                    out.push(natureofbusiness)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            out = input;
        }
        return out;
    }
})
```